# Multi guild member log discord.js v12

Tags: visual-studio, discord.js

Does anyone know how to do welcome and leave messages but it sends the messeges in the channel that the user mentions so it wont be in a specific channel that has a specific name

Example: someone does ?memberlog (channel) it puts the channel they mentioned
Note: I want to learn so no spoonfeed
Note 2: before u say make a database explain HOW

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the sake of simplicity I will narrow down your question down to

> How to persistently store a channel's ID, and then get that channel's ID when I want to send a message

The main point here, as you said, is **databases**. I would recommend you using `SQLite` (a single-file, lightweight database) paired with `keyv` (a simple key-value wrapper which serves your purpose quite well). Additional info on this doesn't really fit in the scope of the `discord.js` tag, so I will just link you to a good guide written on using it ---> https://discordjs.guide/keyv/#installation (read through for the basics on using keyv)

Tip: If you don't have the sqlite file, just create it

Anyways, after you've completed the initial stages (and installed the extension SQLite package via `npm i @keyv/sqlite`), your setup should be looking something like this

```js
const Keyv = require("keyv")
const memberlogs = new Keyv("sqlite://path/to/database/file.sqlite")
```

**Applying your knowledge**

Basically, what you're trying to do in `?memberlog` would be to get the channel mention (and then the ID of the mentioned channel), get the guild id, and then set the guild ID as a key and the channel ID as the value

```js
if(command === "memberlog") {
//grab the channel mention
const proposedChannel = message.mentions.channels.first()

//if there was no channel mention
if(!proposedChannel) return message.channel.send("Mention a channel, dumbo!")

const guildID = message.guild.id
const proposedChannelID = proposedChannel.id

//set key --> value
memberlogs.set(guildID, proposedChannelID)

}
```

Assuming you know the guild of which a member has just joined/left, you can do

```js
//get memberlogs channel
const memberlogChannelID = memberlogs.get(membergoeshere.guild.id)
const memberlogChannel = client.channels.cache.get(memberlogChannelID)

//some code

memberlogChannel.send("Hi!")
```

Note that in this context, I assume you have set up correct event listeners for the `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove` cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a database, please see [here](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/#a-simple-tag-system).
After making a database, you have to log every new user into the database. You should listen for the events `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove`and add or remove users to or from your database. After that, you can just fetch the users form the database using `.findAll()`. You can then use `.map() to map the users.

```js
const users = await Members.findAll();
const all = users.map(i => `${i.name}`);
```

`all` should be an array and you can send it with:

```js
return message.channel.send(all.join(',');
```

Pls remember you have to declare `Members` and the `name` before.

Also if you dont want a database, your best option is:

```js
// Get the Guild and store it under the variable "list"
const list = client.guilds.get("335507048017952771"); 
var users = '';

// Iterate through the collection of GuildMembers from the Guild getting the username property of each member 
list.members.forEach(member => users.concat(member.user.username)); 
return message.channel.send(users);
```

Comment: why use a full blown object-relational mapper? the suggested person only needs simple key-value storage

Comment: yeah, but it will help him with major projects. also i dont think he needs a database for the need he mentioned, getting the users. anyways, keyv will be much simpler, that is true.